My Next app runs well 1st time & doesn't start again after shutdown
Description of the issue.
I recently created a Next App following the docs as I always do. I don't know why, it starts correctly, then, after my production session, my git commit & git push, I shut it down & when I try to restart it, the app is eternally searching on localhost:3000.
Is anyone have an idea why ?
Technical elements
This is the repo : https://github.com/sambarnades/lms-project.git
I use Next.js (React) & Bootstrap 5 for the front-end part, I'm not coding the back-end features for the moment.
Problems' screenshots
When it runs well :

When it searches indefinitely :

I always have to remove the .next folder to restart it correctly.

try these commands
in cmd run netstat -ano | findstr :3000
get the pid and run this taskkill /PID 33728 /F
it will kill the app that already running on port 3000
then try to run the dev server

